# How can I make a google map with user's current place with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

I checked the solution for my problem but all I get are codes made by Google assigned to a static longitude and latitude.

Here is JavaScript Code:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

I want to make it dynamic according to the user location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this one...

http://netmera.com/location/js/geolocation.js 
Adding `geolocation.js` script your html and then below code try.

```
$.geolocation.find(function(location) {
 var lat = location.latitude;
 var lng = location.longitude;

  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the longitude and latitude of your user via the HTML5 GeoLocation API (see [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-html5-geolocation-api/) for example code) and pass the retrieved values.

Comment: Well This is working already,but there is a problem that the **Geolocation API** can't work on old browsers and that is a big issue because I want to integrate the map on a _Web Application_

Comment: Either you disallow old browsers or you ask your user for a zip-code and make a reverse geocoding. Later one has the disadvantage that this might not work country-independent. If both possibilities are not desired I would say that you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use HTML5 Geolocation API. Number of factors: the user has to permit your website to gather info regarding you location, if he doesn't, you won't be able to gather the info. Secondly, even the info is not always accurate. In collecting the location info, the API uses a number of resources, including the location of the server dishing out the page at your current IP address, or it might use the users GPRS service if he is viewing you website in a GPRS enabled device. In either case, chances are not much that you will get the exact location,  you can almost always expect an approximate location.

Comment: Well This is working already,but there is a problem that the **Geolocation API** can't work on old browsers and that is a big issue because I want to integrate the map on a Web Application